# How to use xml2 in R to set attribute on node set

Tags: r, xml, attributes, xml2

I would like to modify all `id` attributes in my node set using the [`xml2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html) package in `R`.

First, we identify the nodes-of-interest.

```
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("<root id='1'><child id ='a' /><child id='b' d='b'/></root>")
nodes <- xml_find_all(x, "//child")  # identify nodes-of-interest

xml_attr(nodes, "id")
#[1] "a" "b"
```

The correct `id` attributes have been extracted.

However, when I try to modify these, I get the same value for all nodes.

```
xml_attr(nodes, "id") <- c("c", "d")
xml_attr(nodes, "id")
#[1] "c" "c"
```

What I expected was:

```
#[1] "c" "d"
```

What is the correct syntax to set up multiple replacements for my node set?

Answer (score 1):

`xml_attr()` or `xml_set_attr()` can only set a single attribute, so elements with the same name will get the same value.

`xml_attrs` or `xml_set_attrs()` can set multiple attributes, but requires namespaces to distinguish elements with the same name.

One solution: iterate over the list of nodes and the replacement values using `purrr::walk2`:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

walk2(nodes, c("c", "d"), ~xml_set_attr(.x, "id", .y))

xml_attr(nodes, "id")
[1] "c" "d"
```